# How to create an effect of eyes opening and closing in first person perspective when awaking from syncope?

Tags: after-effects, premiere, final-cut-pro-x

How to create an effect of eyes opening and closing in first person perspective when awaking from syncope? AE, PR or Final Cut Pro any software is OK. How to create this effect? Or are there any templates or tutorials relating to this?

Comment: When you say syncope, what do you expect to be different than awaking from sleep?

Answer (score 1):

Syncope is also called "blacking out". So it kinda follows that you might fade in from black…? This effect is in every NLE usually as the default transition.

If you wanna get artsy, maybe you could add say, a blur that gets progressively less blurry as the transition proceeds.

But really, it totally depends on what you want it to look like. Is there a director for this video? Making creative decisions about stuff like this is their job.